# TypeError: $(...).tinycarousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, function

Am using Optimizely to try and insert my own carousel as part of an A/B test... but I'm getting this error when dropping the script in to the editor:

TypeError: $(...).tinycarousel is not a function

Am guessing that I need to use something other than document ready but can't find the solution. My function below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#slider1').tinycarousel();
});
```

Comment: where does the `tinycarousel()` function come from?

Comment: Did you include the library script?

Comment: Check the import order of your scripts. If the function is defined somewhere *after* it is called (ie defined in `script2.js` but called in `script1.js`) you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have this order of loading Ressources:

script jquery

script tinycarousel

script document ready